# How to model an inverse relationship with Slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I am trying to model a relationship many-to-many in Slick 3.1.0-M1

This is the example of the Slick documentation

```
// Definition of the SUPPLIERS table
class Suppliers(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, String, String)](tag, "SUPPLIERS") {
  def id = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey) // This is the primary key column
  def name = column[String]("SUP_NAME")
  def street = column[String]("STREET")
  def city = column[String]("CITY")
  def state = column[String]("STATE")
  def zip = column[String]("ZIP")
  // Every table needs a * projection with the same type as the table's type parameter
  def * = (id, name, street, city, state, zip)
}
val suppliers = TableQuery[Suppliers]

// Definition of the COFFEES table
class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)](tag, "COFFEES") {
  def name = column[String]("COF_NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
  def supID = column[Int]("SUP_ID")
  def price = column[Double]("PRICE")
  def sales = column[Int]("SALES")
  def total = column[Int]("TOTAL")
  def * = (name, supID, price, sales, total)
  // A reified foreign key relation that can be navigated to create a join
  def supplier = foreignKey("SUP_FK", supID, suppliers)(_.id)
}
val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees]
```

I would like to be able to write the case class of Suppliers as this

```
case class Supplier(
  id: Int,
  name: String,
  street: String,
  city: String,
  state: String,
  zip: String,
  coffees: List[Coffee]
)
```

I am trying to do it, but at the moment I can not make it work. Also I would like to have methods that allow to update the Supplier object and the Coffee object inside in a cascade mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is simply: **you cannot**. `Slick` is `FRM` (functional relational mapping) and to put it simply - it maps relational tuples onto Scala objects (usually `tuples` / `case classes`). What you want to achieve is not expressed easily in standard SQL, therefore it is not expressible directly in `Slick`. I am specifically mentioning *standard SQL* here - as I am aware that some databases allow you to group and aggregate certain fields into lists or arrays - this is however far outside of standard SQL scope and honestly I am not even sure you would be able to do it in general case.

You can to some extent mimic above in queries by doing `SELECT` with `JOIN` between two tables and later grouping results (important thing here is - results, **I am not talking about SQL `GROUP BY`**) to obtain `coffees` list.

This could be something like this:

First - map your table definitions to cases classes - so instead of:

```
class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)]
```

do this:

```
class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[Coffee]
```

and perhaps rename your existing `Supplier` case class to `SupplierComposite` or whatever else that implies that it doesn't map strictly to db table but is rather a composition of two different tables.

Same with `Supplier`.
It is not strictly required (you would be fine with your tuples) - it will only make things easier.

Then you would run your query like this:

```
db.run(
    (
        suppliers
          join coffees on (_.id === _.supID)
    )
    .result
    .map { results: Seq[(Supplier, Coffee)] =>
        results
            .groupBy(_._1)
            .map { case (supp, groupped) =>
                SupplierComposite(
                    id = supp.id,
                    name = supp.name,
                    ...
                    coffees = groupped.map(_._2)
                )
            }
    }
)
```

It is not possible *whatsoever* to achieve things like this:

> Also I would like to have methods that allow to update the Supplier object and the Coffee object inside in a cascade mode.

Such functions simply don't belong to what `Slick` tries to achieve. It is definitely though within reach of classic `ORM`s - like [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) or (from Scala world) [eBean](http://ebean-orm.github.io/).

Be warned however - this feature (mentioned above) is basically one of the starting points of the root of the problem that is inherent in `ORM`s - namely [object relational impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) - and is precisely the thing that `Slick` wanted to avoid.

Comment: @Pawel_Dolega thank you for your answer, very clear.